# how to get SWF file dimensions in PHP?

Tags: php, flash

how to get SWF file dimensions in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getimagesize` I believe accounts for swfs: http://us.php.net/getimagesize

Comment: it does support that but is this the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You could install and run the [swfdump](http://www.quiss.org/swftools/swfdump.html) utility.

I've also read that PHP's [getimagesize()](http://us.php.net/getimagesize) has some limited support for SWF files.